# Adobe After Effects how can you create a distorted line moving along a video / picture? Example given in desc

Tags: after-effects, video-editor, editing, effects, visual-effects

Saw this on youtube and i would really appreciate if if anyone could explain to me how to do it- The youtube video is below and the distorted libne is in the **intro**:

> 

Thanks,
I've tried looking around for help but cant seem to find any.

Answer (score 2):

You can duplicate your footage and add a displacement map as your revealer with a black line with gradient